# find the only columns with empty values in entire file

Tags: perl, hash

With the below csv data

```
name,place,animal
a,,
b,,
a,,
,b,
```

The name field is available in 3 rows but not available in 1 row
 The place field is available in 1 row but not in 3 row
 The animal field is empty in all the rows -> Get these column names1

i would like to get the column names only if it empty in all the rows.

I am trying to write a perl script for the same but not sure how to attack this problem.

```
step 1: Check all the columns in first row, if any column is not empty ,dont search it in next row
step2: keep repeating step1 in a loop  and finally we will get the output.and this brings down the complexity as we are not bothered about columns that have value even once.
```

i will implement the code and post it here.

But if u have any new ideas, please advise me

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For CSV files with no quotes and escaping, just keep a hash of empty columns so far. Reading the file line by line, remove any non-empty column from the hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

chomp( my @column_names = split /,/, <> );
my %empty;
@empty{ @column_names } = ();

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @columns = split /,/;
    for my $i (0 .. $#columns) {
        delete $empty{ $column_names[$i] } if length $columns[$i];
    }
}

say for keys %empty;
```

For real CSV files, use [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS), but the method is the same: populate a hash by column names, then remove the non empty ones:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Text::CSV_XS qw{ csv };

my %empty;

csv(in      => shift,
    out     => \ 'skip',
    headers => sub { undef $empty{ $_[0] }; $_[0] },
    on_in   => sub {
        my (undef, $columns) = @_;
        delete @empty{ grep length $columns->{$_}, keys %$columns }
    },
);

say for keys %empty;
```

Comment: what if the file has 100million rows , will the first code work, or is there a way we keep deleting the columns from the array which has entire file data initially .

Comment: @LearningCpp: TITS (Try It To See). Both programs keep only the hash of names of the empty columns so far in memory.

Answer (score 2):

As rows are processed update an ancillary array which keeps track of each field's truth-value

If any field in a new row is non-empty the corresponding element of the array flips to true; otherwise it stays false.  In the end indices of array's false elements identify indices of empty columns.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';    
use Text::CSV;

my $file = 'cols.csv';
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1 } ) 
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag (); 

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @col_names = @{ $csv->getline($fh) };

my @mask;
while (my $line = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    @mask = map { $mask[$_] || $line->[$_] ne '' } (0..$#$line);
}

for (0..$#mask) {
    say "Column \"$col_names[$_]\" is empty" if not $mask[$_];
}
```

Syntax: `$#$line` is the index of the last element of arrayref `$line` (like `$#ary` is for `@ary`)